# Modus Tollens / Popperian Syllogism for the Black Swan

Tags: logic, popper

### If it is a swan, then it will always be white.

It seems like Popper is not asking so much people to build **syllogisms**, but rather DEPENDING on Modus Tollens as an engine for falsification.

So that, if I propose -

- If it is a swan, then it will always be white.

And then go ahead and execute my testing model by [traveling to Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan#/media/File:Black_swan.jpg).

Now I have:

If it is a swan, then it will always be white.

I just saw a black swan.

- If A then B
- Not B
- Therefore, Not A

But, here is my confusion: it seems like my hypothesis has some structural issue for Modus Tollens to take effect.

Using what I proposed I get:

- If it is a swan, then it will always be white.
- I just saw a black swan. [Not B]
- It is not a swan. [Not A]

The "it" here suffers dually - from being ambiguous, as you need to stop for a second and figure out that the "it" here refers to the Antecedent "it" in the Conditional statement.

But, **WORSE!** - if I were truly going to go with Not A, saying

"It is not a swan." [Not A]

makes no sense.

So, my question is: **how should I structure the white swan hypothesis Conditional Statement** so that the "Not A" side of the syllogism under the process of Modus Tollens looks a bit more trenchant?

Comment: Despite much thought that  has gone into this question, I still am not clear on what the problem might be. How about “I just saw a non-white swan”? Would that make the terminology more precise?

Comment: Hi Mark.  Seems like what I’m asking may be a more Linguistic question.  For example in: 
If George has a dog, then he is a pet owner.
George is not a pet owner. 
Therefore, George does not have a dog.
Here there is a striking correlation between the parts.  The Conditional, Denying the Consequent and the Conclusion.  It really RINGS out when you read it.  How could we write a Black Swan syllogism to create the same effect?

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is a is a way to rewrite the Conditional so that I can arrive at a 3-part syllogism  - 1[If A, Then B], 2 [Not B], 3 [Therefore, Not A] - that ends in something like "Therefore, not all swans are white."

Comment: black swans, yay!

Answer (score 2):

*It is quite simple*.

The "general law" we have assumed as an hypothesis is :

> "Every swan is white"

that, according to the language of predicate logic, is :

> (1) "for every **x**, if **x** is a Swan, then **x** is White" [in symbols : **∀x(S(x) → W(x))**].

Yoy are travelling in Australia and you find a black swan, that is :

> (2) "there is an **x** such that, **x** is a Swan and **x** not is White" [in symbols : **∃x(S(x) ∧ ¬W(x))**] .

Call that Swan **s**; from (2), by [Existential instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation) we have :

> **S(s) ∧ ¬ W(s)**.

Form (1), by [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) we have :

> **S(s) → W(s)**.

But the two formula are contradictory,  because **P ∧ ¬Q** is the negation of **P →  Q**, and thus we have to conclude with the negation of the initial hypothesis, i.e. we have *falsified* the purported "general law" :

> "Every swan is white".

---

The argument above can be expressed also with [Modus Tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens).

We have **S(s) → W(s)** and from **S(s) ∧ ¬ W(s)**, by [Simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) we get : **S(s)** and **¬ W(s)**.

Now we have : **S(s) → W(s)** and **¬ W(s)** and by *MT* we conclude with :

> **¬ S(s)**.

This contradicts **S(s)** and we are done.

---

---

It is not exactly a [Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Basic_structure) because a syllogism needs three *terms*, like e.g.: **S,P** and **M**.

In our example, we have only two : **S**wan and **W**hite.

Thus the inference is :

> 1st premise :  "All Swans are White" [A-type : Universal Affirmative : "All **S** are **W**"]
>
> 2nd premise : "Some Swans are not White" [O-type : Particular Negative : "Some **S** are not **W**"]

With them, we may have a valid [*Baroco*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Baroco_(AOO-2)) syllogism, concluding in O-type : Particular Negative.

In fact, the conclusion we have reached denying the first premise :

> > "Not every Swan is White" ["Not all **S** are **W**"]

is a Particular Negative, because it amounts to "Some Swans are not White" ["Some **S** are not **W**"].

Comment: Hi!  When I read your reply I felt impressed.  I think you're right.  You've illustrated the mechanics of Modus Tollens clearly.  Seems like I may be asking a question more related to the linguistic structure of the syllogism.  For example: If George plays tennis he will wear sunscreen.  He is not wearing sunscreen.  He will not play tennis.  These's such a tight linguistic correlation there between the elements of the Conditional, Denying the Consequent, to the Conclusion.  Rings out just like a bell.  How could we write the Black Swan syllogism to get the same effect?

Comment: I was about to answer, but your answer is already in-depth and to the point, bravo +1

Comment: @SmootQ - you are welcome :-)